# Minecraft Lastlogin decrypt c#

Tags: c#, minecraft

I'm making a Minecraft modpack launcher with c#.
How do I get the username and password from the lastlogin file and also how to write to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to securely save username/password (local)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657792/how-to-securely-save-username-password-local)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of a project called [Craft.Net](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/Craft.Net), and it can do what you're looking for.

Use the Craft.Net.Client library, and you can use the [Craft.Net.Client.LastLogin](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/Craft.Net/blob/master/source/Craft.Net.Client/LastLogin.cs) class to read from or write to the lastlogin file. It's MIT licensed, so you could also just pull out only the parts that you need.