# Hashing Passwords. Safe?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, encryption

I have no code to post as this is just a general question.

I currently have a web site where I have authentication setup. I have members of the site and I store their credentials in a database. This works perfectly fine. Common sense applies here and I do know that I shouldn't store user information as plain text. However, as I was researching things, I saw that hashing strings something quite easy to do. Throughout my development I saw that there is also a way to de-hash these passwords which led me to this question. Is just hashing the password enough? Should I be doing some kind of encryption along with it? What is the best practice? I haven't found any good information on the web...

`string dec = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Login1.Password, "SHA1");`
Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

Comment: Make sure you use a unique salt for each user, and try to use a password hashing algorithm instead of a (edit: purely) cryptographic one.  Encryption isn't very useful as the decryption key needs to be stored on the same server as the data.  If one is compromised, it's likely both will.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin good hashing algorithms *are* cryptographic.

Comment: @zespri Good point, that was a bit misleading. I've made it sort of clearer.  As someone has already posted a bcrypt implementation I glossed over that part a bit.

Comment: From your description it does not look like there is a necessity to reinvent the wheel. You can use standard .Net facilities like this one: [Crypto.HashPassword Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) I'm not sure what exactly you refer to when you mention de-hashing as hash functions are made on purpose very difficult to reverse.

Comment: `de-hashing`: i.e. via brute-force, or preparing rainbow tables (huge dictionary look-ups of random strings to their hashed value)

Comment: Without any supporting links "also a way to de-hash these passwords" (which whole question is based on) this question does not look a bit weak. There are many questions discussing the issues like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657792/how-to-securely-save-username-password-local?lq=1.  It is also somewaht hard to belive that there is no information on [C# hash password](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+hash+password) on the internet... [Hashing passwords - MSDN Magazine, 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164107.aspx) may be a start...

Comment: You should give me a +1 for my question then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to [take a look at `bcrypt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), as hash functions although reasonably secure (as long as you salt your inputs!), become weaker over time.

The key to the `bcrypt` algorithm is that the difficulty is configurable and so this method scales even as computers become more and more powerful:

> Cryptotheoretically, this is no stronger than the standard Blowfish
>   key schedule, but the number of rekeying rounds is configurable; this
>   process can therefore be made arbitrarily slow, which helps deter
>   brute-force attacks upon the hash or salt.

An implementation of [bcrypt for C# is available here](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/).

Comment: and you want to add some salt so that two people with the same password (in your system or across systems) don't end up with the same hash.