# Most secure storage username/password, config file, python

Tags: python, security, passwords, config

I have a script that makes various API calls. This script will be run unassisted, so I need to store the login credentials to these and other services in a local config file.

I'm pretty sure it's a horrible idea to store this sensitive data in plaintext in a .txt file. How can I do this more securely?

I saw a similar question but the answers were very C# specific. [How to securely save username/password (local)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657792/how-to-securely-save-username-password-local)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to securely store a username and password in Python, what are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options)

Answer (score 5):

If you encrypt the file, how are you going to protect the key that encrypted it? You're going to buy an expensive HSM is what you're going to do.

Barring that, a good, general solution is as follows:

1. Create an OS user, say `foo`
2. Create a (permanent) OS environment variable for user `foo`, with the login password
3. Make `foo` the owner of the script and only give `foo` right to run that script
4. Run the script as user `foo`
5. Read the OS environment variable in your script

Only `foo` or `root` can read `foo`'s OS environment variables. Root can always read everything anyways.

Comment: It is possible to remain in the config file so long as access to the file is tightly controlled such that only Root and Foo may read the file and nobody can modify the file.

Comment: @micker no. your solution is local and mine is general. yours will not work for open source projects

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like this https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html

I have seen this used to store credentials for severs in an object database.